# Elegant way to get T type from ObservableCollection<T> in .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, types, observablecollection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# generic list <T> how to get the type of T?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043755/c-sharp-generic-list-t-how-to-get-the-type-of-t)

This is a simple question. What is the most elegant and simple way to get
the type  of an ObservableCollection of unknown type?

I have a method:

```
public void DoSomething(object oc)
{
     //I know 'oc' is a ObservableCollection<T> 
     //How to get its type <T> without having to do
     //obj.GetType().GetProperties().....
}
```

Thanks

Comment: That's true, I"ll delete it then. Sorry about that..

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the collection to a generic function

```
public static void AddUnknown<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> collection, object item){
      collection.Add((T)item);
}
```

That can then be used like `collection.AddUnknown(obj)`

if the compiler does not know which ObservableCollection you are using you will have to supply that information unless you are willing to use reflection

Comment: And do you know of a simple and elegant way to get the Type <T> out of the collection? I tried this: `        public static T GetType<T>(ObservableCollection<T> collection)
        {
            return T;
        }` but I get an error saying Type parameter name not valid at this point.

Comment: depends on what you meen by get it out. One way would be through GetGenericTypeArguments()

Answer (score 1):

You can write an extension method that does it for you

```
public static Type GetGenericType<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> o)
{
    return typeof(T);
}
```

Have a look here as well: [C# Get Generic Type Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185521/c-sharp-get-generic-type-name)

Edit:

This is very interesting :)

I came up with a solution that uses dynamic

```
public static void DoSomething(object o)
{
 var iCollection = o as ICollection;
 if(iCollection != null)
 {
    dynamic oc = iCollection;
    Type t = GetGenericType(oc); 
    // now you got your type :)
 }
}

public static Type GetGenericType<T>( List<T> o)
{
    return typeof(T);
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that your sample method receives an observablecollection object. I need it to receive an object of object type which is an ObservableCollection but not explicitly...

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, to work with the object:

- using reflection (you told it is undesirable)
- trial and error
- using a base class or interface that is broad enough

**Trial and error**

Try all the variations, that you expect to be possible:

```
var list1 = oc as ObservableCollection<int>;
var list2 = oc as ObservableCollection<string>;
var list3 = oc as ObservableCollection<MyClass>;

if (list1 != null)
    list1.Add(1);

else if (list2 != null)
    list2.Add("str");

else if (list3 != null)
    list3.Add(new MyClass());

else
    throw new Exception("Unexpected object type.");
```

**Using broad base class**

```
 var list = oc as IList;
 list.Add(value);
```