# How do I print the name of generic classes in c#?

Tags: c#, reflection

Is there a simple way to obtain the name of a class in c# including template parameters?

I.E

```
Print( new List<int>{ 100, 1001});
```

Produce one of the following outputs:

```
List<int>
List<Int32>
System.Collections.Generics.List<System.Int32>
```

one of the first 2 is preferrable, but `Type.FullName` is not a viable option. It is ways too verbose.

Too verbose result that is unwanted.

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=235hosehoue5h]]
```

Note I'm asking just for a shortcut if it exists. I'm no asking for a full implementation of such feature.

Comment: These are not "template parameters", these are "generic type parameters". They are different. Generics in C# are not like templates in C++.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(typeof(List<int>))` produces `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Int32]`. Whats wrong with that?

Comment: Missing angle brackets, no good for nested template types for readability => `System.Console.WriteLine(typeof(List<Tuple<List<int>,List<char>>>));` prints `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Tuple'2[System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Int32],System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Char]]]`

Comment: [How about this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26429045/106159). Maybe not what I'd class as "simple" though...

Comment: @UberFace there is nothing missing, thats just the reflection notation. Maybe its worth asking what do you want to do with these strings? For debug reasons for example it should not matter.

Comment: cool @MatthewWatson then mine answer was duplicate. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Create a method to get the class Name.

1. there is a property in `Type` class `Type.IsGenericType`, which mean this type whether is genericType.
2. use `Type.GenericTypeArguments` to get all arguments of the generic type the use linq to combine them by `,`.
3. If the class is generic contain generic you can use function recursively to get the name. Thanks for @Eric Lippert point out.

look like this.

```
public static class ExtensionLib {
    public static string GetClassName(this Type objType)
    {

        string result = objType.Name;
        if (objType.IsGenericType)
        {
            var name = objType.Name.Substring(0, objType.Name.IndexOf('`'));
            var genericTypes = objType.GenericTypeArguments;
            result = $"{name}<{string.Join(",", genericTypes.Select(GetClassName))}>";
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MRtVkz)

**Input**

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(List<int>).GetClassName());
Console.WriteLine(typeof(List<List<int>>).GetClassName());  
Console.WriteLine(typeof(Dictionary<List<int>,string>).GetClassName());
```

**Result**

```
List<Int32>
List<List<Int32>>
Dictionary<List<Int32>,String>
```

Comment: You're so close but not quite right. What happens if you have `List<List<int>>` with your program? Do you see how to fix it?

Comment: @EricLippert Good catch. I edit my answer use function recursive

Comment: Your fix works but it is needlessly complicated. The recursive call already checks for generic type, so you could just say `genericTypes.Select(x => x.GetClassName())`.  In fact, you can make it even shorter than that. You can simply say `genericTypes.Select(GetClassName)` and C# will figure out what you meant.

Comment: @EricLippert Wow Thanks new learn. You are so awesome . Could I use your idea in my answer :)

Comment: Of course, go for it!