# How to get simplified ReturnType through MethodInfo?

Tags: c#, reflection, code-documentation, methodinfo

Using reflection to obtain a MethodInfo, I want to get a more user-friendly version of the ReturnType for some self-documentation.

Currently this
`methodInfo.ReturnType.Name` returns something like Dictionary`2 or IEnumerable`1.

While this `methodInfo.ReturnType.FullName;` returns a far too lengthy version like `` System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral]] ``

or `` System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[ProjectName.Namespace.Item, ProjectName, Version=1.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] ``

I could theoretically do some string manipulation to get rid of all of the excess information being displayed, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Get Generic Type Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185521/c-sharp-get-generic-type-name) . Check a most voted answer there

Comment: Yes, that answer was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

with a little bit of string manipulation you can easily build the nice name yourself recursively:

```
private static string NiceName(Type t)
{
    var indexOfH = t.Name.IndexOf('`');
    return (indexOfH >= 0 ? t.Name.Substring(0, indexOfH) : t.Name) + (t.IsGenericType ? $"<{string.Join(",", t.GenericTypeArguments.Select(NiceName))}>" : "");
}
```