# How to get properties of type T in Task<T> using reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am trying to get the properties of a return type of a method using reflection.

I am getting the return type of the method using `MethodInfo.ReturnType`, which yields my a type of `Task<T>` since my method is `async`. Using `GetProperties` on this type yields me with the properties belonging to `Task`: `Result`, `Exception`, `AsyncState`. However, I want to get the properties of the underlying type T.

Example for method with signature:

```cs
public async Task<MyReturnType> MyMethod()
```

```cs
var myMethodInfo = MyType.GetMethod("MyMethod");
var returnType = myMethodInfo.ReturnType; // Task<MyReturnType>
var myProperties = returnType.GetProperties(); // [Result, Exception, AsyncState]
```

How can I get the properties of the inner type T in Task in stead of the properties of Task?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Get Generic Type Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185521/c-sharp-get-generic-type-name)

Comment: @Klamsi Not quite, as it seems that will get Task in stead of T. I have now answered my own question, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can determine if the type is a `Task` with the method `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` and get the generic type arguments with the property `GenericTypeArguments`.

In this case:

```cs
var myMethodInfo = MyType.GetMethod("MyMethod");
var returnType = myMethodInfo.ReturnType;

if (returnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Task<>)) {
    var actualReturnType = returnType.GenericTypeArguments[0]; // MyReturnType
    var myProperties = actualReturnType.GetProperties(); // The properties of MyReturnType!
}
```