# Convert CLR type names to equivalent idiomatic C# aliases (eg System.String => string, Int32 => int)

Tags: c#

I am parsing some objects and I'd like to dynamically generate some code.
The thing is that when I'm reading types I got things like :

```
System.String
System.Int32
Boolean
```

I know it's strictly identical for C# to string, int and bool. But when I'm parsing my object, i got the "System" versions and I want to dynamically generate some code using strings and I want to generate the alias description, can I do it easyly ? (without something like a Dictionary associating typeofs to strings...)

Comment: had never paid attention to it, fixing it !

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 'parsing some objects', show some code!

Comment: I edited your title to avoid confusion, because "type conversion" is a quite different thing.

Comment: You can't do this. The ones you get are the actual types, "int", "string", etc. are nothing but aliases.

Comment: @James ooh, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99812/who-has-the-power-to-delete-a-comment then I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do this.  However, there are not that many types so if it were me I would probably just write a mapping function.

You can find the list of C# type names here as a starting point:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86792hfa(VS.71).aspx

Update: here is a reference for C# which includes decimal.  Not sure why that was missing from above link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx

Comment: Strange, "decimal" is missing from that table. It's included in the tables that the other two answers link to.

Answer (score 1):

string and int are aliases for System.String and System.Int32.

Seems like you can use this to get the Types from strings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codetypeofexpression.aspx

```
// Creates a reference to the System.Int32 type.
CodeTypeReference int32typeRef = new CodeTypeReference("System.Int32");
```

But there is no way to get a string from type so you have to define your own mapping there:
[Is there a way to get a type's alias through reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362884/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-types-alias-through-reflection)

Comment: I wanted to avoid this and I'll create the association mapping myself :(

Comment: and I can get a string from "dateTimeTypeRef" and "int32typeRef" ? I tried toString() but I got : System.CodeDom.CodeTypeReference

Comment: No you can't :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362884/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-types-alias-through-reflection

Answer (score 1):

Once you compile the code you write in C# it no longer knows it came from C# code, therefore there is no way to automatically get the C# alias without doing exactly what you suggest - create a simple mapping dictionary.

The built in C# types are listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ya5y69ds.aspx

This list is not going to change any time soon, as I shouldn't worry about hard coding this list into your application.